# What does week23.UniversityProblem.Lesson@77459877 mean?

Tags: java

I was working on a problem for a club and tried to run it, here is the code:

```
package week23.UniversityProblem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniversityProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lesson math101 = new Lesson();
        math101.name = "Mathematics";
        math101.credit = 4;
        Lesson phys101 = new Lesson();
        phys101.name = "Physics";
        phys101.credit = 3;
        Lesson cs102 = new Lesson();
        cs102.name = "Computer Science";
        cs102.credit = 3;
        Lesson ictapp = new Lesson();
        ictapp.name = "Ict applications";
        ictapp.credit = 3;
        Lesson rs101 = new Lesson();
        rs101.name = "Romainian Studies";
        rs101.credit = 3;
        int o = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (o != 2){
            System.out.println("What option do you want to use:");
            System.out.println("1. Add & Print");
            System.out.println("2. Exit");
            o = scanner.nextInt();
            if(o == 1){
                Student s = new Student();
                System.out.println("Name:");
                s.name = scanner2.nextLine();
                int c = 0;
                int o2 = 0;
                while(c < s.maxCredit){
                    System.out.println("What course would you like to take:");
                    System.out.println("1. " + math101.name);
                    System.out.println("2. " + phys101.name);
                    System.out.println("3. " + cs102.name);
                    System.out.println("4. " + ictapp.name);
                    System.out.println("5. " + rs101.name);
                    System.out.println("6. Exit");
                    o2 = scanner.nextInt();
                    if(o2 == 1){
                      s.arr2.add(math101);
                      c += math101.credit;
                    } else if (o2 == 2) {
                        s.arr2.add(phys101);
                        c += phys101.credit;
                    } else if (o2 == 3) {
                        s.arr2.add(cs102);
                        c += cs102.credit;
                    } else if (o2 == 4) {
                        s.arr2.add(ictapp);
                        c += ictapp.credit;
                    } else if (o2 == 5) {
                        s.arr2.add(rs101);
                        c += rs101.credit;
                    } else if (o2 == 6) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(s.name + " ");
                for (int i = 0; i < s.arr2.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(s.arr2.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my lesson class and it's attributes:

```
package week23.UniversityProblem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lesson {
    String name;
    int credit;
}
```

And here is my Student class and it's attributes. Also, my arraylist is in the Student class. All of my lessons are stored in this arraylist. At the end I want to display student name and his/her lesson names with credits

```
package week23.UniversityProblem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {
    String name;
    int maxCredit = 10;
    ArrayList<Lesson> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

After choosing my options from the menu i added, here is what it displays:

```
Tudor
week23.UniversityProblem.Lesson@77459877
week23.UniversityProblem.Lesson@5b2133b1
```

Comment: This is the "memory address" of that instance of `week23.UniversityProblem.Lesson` and is the default behavior of calling `.ToString()`. If you override the `public String toString()` in your `Lesson` class, you can change what it will say.

Comment: Try this instead: `System.out.println(s.name + " "); System.out.println("Courses:\n========"); for (Lesson lesson : s.arr2) { System.out.println("  Name:   " + lesson.name); System.out.println("  Credit: " + lesson.credit); System.out.println("--------------------------\n"); }`

Answer (score 0):

The `Lesson` class does not override the `toString()` method provided by the `Object` class (which all objects extend directly if they are not declared to extend some other object).  As such, the JRE will use the `toString()` method of the `Object` class.  The javadoc for that implementation states that this will be

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you get in your console is the **hashcode value** of an object. Since the object has **no toString** method to determine how it should be printed as a String. It instead prints the hashcode value which is the output you are receiving.

There are multiple ways to solve this issue. Here is one example: Add a toString method to your Lesson class:

```
 public String toString(){//overriding the toString() method  
  return "Name: "+name+", Credit: "+credit;  
 }
```